# How to view tokens in quanteda after applying a dictionary

Tags: r, nlp, access-token, text-mining, quanteda

This is my first time asking a question here, so pleace excuse, if I am not handling it appropriately.
I used the R package quanteda to analyse text documents.

My problem is now that I would like to see the text after I applied the dictionary that I developed. In order to apply the dictionary I tokenized the corpus, but then I couldn't find a function or method which allows me to see the tokenized text. I looked at the quanteda website and the cheat sheet but couldn't find any solution. 
This is basically the important part of my code:

```
tokens_text_dict <- tokens_text %>% 
  tokens_lookup(dict_Info_priv, exclusive = FALSE)
```

EDIT: Moved code from comment to question:

```
text1 <- "a b c"
corpus1 <- corpus(text1)
tokens <- tokens(corpus1)
dict1 <- dictionary(list(A = "a")
tokens1_dict <- tokens_text %>% 
   tokens_lookup(dict1, exclusive = FALSE)
```

I am looking for the command which would give the "A b c", which should now be in tokens1_dict.

I would appreciate some help a lot!

Best wishes

Yannick

Comment: I would like to see the text after the dictionary was applied. So if :

`text1 <- "a b c";

corpus1 <- corpus(text1);

tokens <- tokens(corpus1);

dict1 <- dictionary(list(A = "a");


tokens1_dict <- tokens_text %>% 
  tokens_lookup(dict1, exclusive = FALSE);
`

then I am looking for the command which would give the "A b c", which should now be in tokens1_dict.


If it's possible

Comment: Moved your code example from the comment to the question. Answer by @Ken Benoit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two easy ways to view your tokens.  In quanteda v2, there are options for printing the tokens object to the console.  (See `` ?`print-quanteda` ``)

```
> print(tokens1_dict, max_ndoc = -1, max_ntok = -1)
Tokens consisting of 1 document.
text1 :
[1] "A" "b" "c"
```

Or, can use the `View()` function, which calls the display method for inspecting a list (of which a tokens object is a special type).  This action is also triggered in RStudio by clicking on the object's name from the Environment pane.

```
> View(tokens1_dict)
```

[image]